# Latest Analysis in SonarQube 5.5 removes other projects

Tags: sonarqube

I have two gradle projects with different names which run sonar analysis.  They both build and will successfully show analysis in SonarQube.  The problem though is that when Project A builds it's analysis shows in SonarQube, but then when I run Project B then Sonar ONLY shows Project B and the analysis that was previously visible for Project A is gone from Sonar.

How do I get both projects analysis to exist in SonarQube simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As G. Ann pointed out below (thank you).  The projects were replacing each other and you have give each project a **unique** project key.

So in the build.gradle for project A I added:

```
sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.projectKey", "projectA"
  }
}
```

So in the build.gradle for project B I added:

```
sonarqube {
  properties {
    property "sonar.projectKey", "projectB"
  }
}
```

That distinguishes the projects in Sonar and now I am seeing both project simultaneously.

Comment: You might expand this slightly to say that the projects were replacing each other & you had to distinguish the two with _unique_ project key values.

Comment: Thanks G. Ann I made those changes.